# Python regular expression to remove only specific square brackets and question mark in a string by leaving other square brackets unchanged

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am trying to remove only specific pattern in a string using regEx which includes brackets and question marks and also by not changing of other brackets

Here is the code which I was trying

```
import re
string = "aaaa{v?}a $1?{23ru{n?}kkkk"
pattern = '[{?}]'
replace = ''

new_string = re.sub(pattern, replace, string) 
print(new_string)
```

It generates below output
"aaaava $123runkkkk"

I want the output to be like below

"aaaava $1?{23runkkkk"

You can notice that it removed {v?}, {n?} bracket({}) and question mark(?) only in this format
There is unchange of brackets and question marks at the remaining places.

Comment: Do you mean to remove `{` + letter + `?}`? `re.sub(r'{[a-z]\?}', '', text)`? Or anything inside `{...?}` (between `{` and `}` where text ends with `?`)?

Comment: Yeah, you're almost correct. But I want to keep character in this pattern "aaaa{v?}a", expected output "aaaava".

Comment: Right, so the letter needs capturing, `re.sub(r'{([a-z])\?}', r'\1', text)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'{([a-z])\?}', r'\1', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LwYlYR/1). *Details*:

- `{` - a `{` char
- `([a-z])` - Group 1 (`\1` refers to this group text from the replacement pattern): any lowercase ASCII letter
- `\?` - a `?` char
- `}` - a `}` char.

Comment: @Mr.ML.Engineer Thank you comments are off-topic. Please visit the SO site guide to see how to thank those who provide answers for your questions.